# How to implement OAuth 2 on server

Tags: c#, api, oauth

I am trying to implement *OAuth2* for [this](https://btcjam.com/faq/api) particular *API* in *C#*.
I want to implement it on my backend server for my own personal usage, with my own account, not for other users. My backend isn't a web application, so I don't really have a redirect_uri to authorize my "application". How can I solve this issue, as I do need the response_code to get the token and start using the protected API calls.

Answer (score 1):

Try rmjoia's advice, it's (one of) the best options for .NET
See [the source](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/) and [client implementations](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients)

I have used them myself.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like that to secure multiple Web APIs using [this](https://identityserver.github.io/), have you tried it yet?

The [documentation](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/) is very straight forward, and I've implemented my solution using it, a bit of try and error.